# Excel countif vba code with criteria resulting with values

Tags: vba, excel, conditional-statements, countif

I am not sure if what I want to achieve is possible. So here it is:

I got workbook with 2 sheets:

First sheet cointains raw data with employees and trainings they did or did not take (they could not come to the the training). Sheets cointains few columns like: name, special ID (different for every employee), 2 blank columns, presence (yes/no), and few more...

Second sheet will create report based on range and presence criteria.

Technically it's something like that:

Report sheet has list of employees, they will be filtered using autofilter. Those filtered employees will be checked if they were on 14 categories of trainings. Categories differs with range (ranges are known; with time ranges will be added or adjusted to newly added trainings).

**My problem:**
Is it possible to create vba code that will check if employee was on certain trainings (countif in certain range with condition: not present = do not count) and paste the value to certain cells? If it is could you give some advice on how to do that? I am not asking for ready code.

**Trying to make it work but I stuck at this. Error at line "if cells.find...".**

```
Sub Check()

MyRange = Range("A1", Selection.End(xlDown))

For Each MyCell In MyRange
With Range("pp2dni2007")
    If Cells.Find(MyCell.Value) Is Nothing Then

    Else
        If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value Then
        MyCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = 1

        Else
        MyCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = 0

        End If

    End If

End With
Next

End Sub
```

2nd edit, earlier code did infinite loop. Now I think if-statements reference to wrong range but not sure how to deal with it.

```
Sub Check()

Dim MyRange As Range, MyCell As Variant

Range("A1").Select

Set MyRange = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
    With Range("pp2dni2007")
        If .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value) Is Nothing Then

        Else
            If .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value).Value = .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value).Offset(0, 3).Value Then
            MyCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = 1

            Else
            MyCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = 0

            End If

        End If

    End With
Next

End Sub
```

Sample workbook: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/7421442/sample%20workbook%20(1).xls

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you're not asking for code, what *are* you asking for?

Comment: Well, I am not sure how to approach the problem. Macro should contain actions like: insert formula to filtered cells and then copy-paste as values. Or there is another way to run formula through macro and paste only values? I would like ask for some sample code if second option is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare all your variables, e.g.,

`Dim MyRange as Range, MyCell as Range`.

Without declaration, `MyCell` is variant data type, and that is why you're getting an `Object Required` error.  Then do:

```
For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
```

Inside the `With` block, you may want to use (note the `.` in front of `Cells`):

```
If .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value) Is Nothing Then
```

Further, you will probably need to revise what you're doing with `ActiveCell`, since this is never changing which cell is active, I'm not sure it would give you the expected results.   It is always preferable to avoid relying on `Active` and `Select` methods (except for to use them as user-input).  INstead, work with the range objects directly.

Comment: Thanks, it is somehow step forward, but still it is not perfect. Updated code.

Comment: I think I know where is the problem! There are two ranges: MyRange (corresponding to employee ID) and pp2dni2007 (corresponding to employee ID but in another sheet with training list). If-statements must correspond to range pp2dni2007 not MyRange (currently it reference to MyRange). How to deal with it?

Comment: Unless you have changed your code, the `If` statements you use are conditional on `Range("pp2dni2007")`.  I do not understand what you're asking.  Since this has solved your immediate problem/error, please consider marking this answer as accepted, and asking a new question to help with your syntax/logic errors.

Comment: Um... I think it is not because it does not work correctly - I checked. Maybe code looks ok but somehow it works differently than I expect. I will try to provide you sample data when I get back home.

Comment: Try maybe `With worksheet_name_.Range("pp2dni2007")` where you may need to add the worksheet name on which the range "pp2dni2007" is located.

Comment: I will try do as you wrote when I'll be at work. For now I edited question adding link to sample workbook.

Comment: David you were right. Ranges are set ok, problem was with my if-statement. I changed it and now it works fine. Thanks for help and patience :)