# For each cell with different ranges?

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, range

I have a macro which checks for each cell of filtered column results. It checks for 14 different ranges. 
I was wondering, is it possible to somehow cut my code so I don't have to copy/paste same instruction to different ranges? I was thinking about using dictionary but I am not sure is this a good solution plus have no idea how to mix for each with checking different ranges and inserting results in a different places. Below I provide you a code:

```
Sub check_training()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim MyCell As Variant
Dim strAddress As String

Set MyRange = Range([a1], [a1].End(xlDown)).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

'PP 2dni 2007
For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
    With Range("pp2dni2007")
    Set rng1 = .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

            If Not IsEmpty(MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value) Then

            Else

                strAddress = rng1.Address
                Do



                        If .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value).Offset(0, 3).Value = "TAK" Then

                        MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value = MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value + 1

                        Else
                        MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value = 0

                        End If

                Set rng1 = .Cells.FindNext(rng1)
                Loop While rng1.Address <> strAddress

            End If

        End If

    End With

Next


'PP 3dni 2008
liczba = liczba + 1
For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
    With Range("pp3dni2008")
    Set rng1 = .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value)
        If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then

            If Not IsEmpty(MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value) Then

            Else

                strAddress = rng1.Address
                Do

                    If .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value).Offset(0, 3).Value = "TAK" Then
                    MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value = MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value + 1

                    Else
                    MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value = 0

                    End If

                Set rng1 = .Cells.FindNext(rng1)
                Loop While rng1.Address <> strAddress

            End If

        End If

    End With
Next

(and so on...)

End sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a sub with the code you would otherwise copy paste, and then pass the variable factors as parameters to that function. In turn, call the function with all the necessary strings. I have to admit, I'm having trouble making any sense of your code, but I've tried my best to extract a function

```
Public Sub rangeOperation(MyRange as Range, rangeString as String, liczba as Integer)
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Dim MyCell As Variant
    Dim strAddress As String

    For Each MyCell In MyRange.Cells
        With Range(rangeString)
        Set rng1 = .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value)
            If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
                If Not IsEmpty(MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value) Then

            Else
                strAddress = rng1.Address
                Do
                    If .Cells.Find(MyCell.Value).Offset(0, 3).Value = "TAK" Then                   
                        MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value = MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value + 1   
                    Else
                        MyCell.Offset(0, liczba).Value = 0
                    End If
                Set rng1 = .Cells.FindNext(rng1)
                Loop While rng1.Address <> strAddress
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

You can then call this function from wherever your code is now like this:

```
Dim MyRange as Range
dim rangeString as String
dim liczba as Integer

Set MyRange = Range([a1], [a1].End(xlDown)).Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
rangeString = "pp2dni2007"
liczba = 0 ' or whatever value...

Call rangeOperation(MyRange, rangeString, liczba)

liczba = liczba + 1
rangeString = "pp3dni2008"

Call rangeOperation(MyRange, rangeString, liczba)
```

Etc. As I have no idea what your function does, you'll have to figure out other parts that need to be more variable. The next step is then to put your strings in some kind of collection/dictionary/array and loop over that data structure, calling the function from within the loop.

Comment: Ok, I probably should have added information about functionality of this workbook earlier... Check here for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248630/excel-countif-macro-with-criteria-resulting-with-values

Comment: ...and about your anwser, I think somehow it may help me. I need to check it first. If you got better idea after reading given link, please share it :)

Comment: Okay, I analized your code. If I understood your anwser then `With Range("pp2dni2007")` should be `With Range(rangeString)`, am I right?

Comment: Absolutely, that somehow went MIA when copy/pasting.

Comment: Brilliant, it works :) Maybe it was not the thing I originally had in mind but makes code easier. Thanks!